# Symfony2 error expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have one to many relationship between Roles and UserRoles.

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PNC\PermissionsBundle\Entity\UserRoles", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $usersRole;
}

class UserRoles {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PNC\PermissionsBundle\Entity\Roles", inversedBy="usersRole", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $role;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="usersRole", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
}


class Roles {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PNC\PermissionsBundle\Entity\UserRoles", mappedBy="role", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $usersRole;
}
```

I need to insert into the UserRoles Entity. I only have $user as object but $role as id.

```
$user_roles = new UserRoles();
$role = $em->getRepository('PNCPermissionsBundle:Roles')->findRoleByID($id);

$user_roles->setRole($role if(is_object($role)){
                    var_dump('it is an object...');exit;
                }else{
                    var_dump('it is not an object...');exit;
                });
$user_roles->setUser($user);
$user_roles->setIsPrimary(false);
$em->persist($user_roles);
$em->flush();
```

and the **RoleRepository** Function is as

```
public function findRoleByID($role_id){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->select('r.id')
            ->Where('r.id = :role_id')
            ->setParameter('role_id', $role_id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
            ;
    }
```

what i understand is that $roles is now behave as an integer, but it should be an object of Roles Entity.

The REsult of `var_dump` is

```
string(22) "it is not an object..."
```

How can id do this in my Scenario....?

Comment: What you posted looks like it should work.  Are you sure is it complaining about setRole?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the same without UserRoles Object!

Try for $user->roles

```
 /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    protected $roles;
```

And for $role->users

```
 /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;
```

and a method in User entity -->

```
   /**
     * @param Role $role
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addRole(Role $role)
    {
        $this->roles->add($role);
        return $this;
    }
```

So your action will look like:

```
$user->addRole($role);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Notice the $user_roles->setIsPrimary(false); line?  He wants additional attributes on UserRole.

Comment: Would be great to find out in what context it is used.

Comment: He wants to have multiple roles with one of them marked as primary.  A little bit unusual but that is okay.  And of course Doctrine's ManyToMany relation does not support additional attributes.

Comment: An exception message would be nice to look at. Unfortunately I can't comment this under his question. I think I had similar issue with Doctrine and the solution was is to set user_id and role_id directly rather than via Objects.

Comment: Well, the crux of Doctrine 2 Object Relation Manager is objects.  You very seldom deal with id's directly.  An error message would be nice.  As posted, the question does not make much sense.

Comment: @Cerad @alexsila . I also think about using `raw sql` query to put `user_id` and `role_id` into  `user_roles table`, but in that case i have to provide the `Identity` `$id` of `UserRoles` entity, that is what i don't wanted too also.